# Google review SMS Permission Issue

Tags: android-permissions

I have use sms permission in background to send sms using the SMSManager.

Code is here:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(1234567890, null, mStrSMSText, null, null);
```

Declare permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Also ask permission run time for marshmallow and up version.

In Google permission declaration form use `DEFAULT_SMS` but not allow showing below message.

Thanks for contacting the Google Play team about your app Thieves Alert, com.xyz.xyz. We reviewed your app and found that it does not qualify for use of the requested permissions for the following reasons:

> The declared functionality DEFAULT_SMS  is determined to be
>   unnecessary or not aligned with the core functionality of your app.
>   Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but
>   your app has no default handler capability.

Please help me to solve the issue, thanks.

Comment: also facing same issue. got mail from google. you got solution ?

Comment: No @ShivanshuVerma

Answer (score 0):

SMS permission is used by many apps for fraud or malware. So Google is cracking down on the use of this permission, and has changed the rules for it.

- [The rules are here](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)
- [A help centre page is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)
- [A blog post explaining it is here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html)

The help center article gives a ways of accomplishing what you need to, without asking for the permission.

Let me expand giving an example of how the above articles could help you solve the issue.

- Your app has the name "Thieves Alert" according to your question
- I don't know why you want SMS Permission. If [this is your app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.j2mlinfotech.thievesalert) it says nothing in the app description about using SMS. This is one bad sign. If you need SMS permission for something, it should be obvious why for the user from the App description. Otherwise you could be malware, trying to steal money from the user by sending SMS to premium rate numbers.
- Tip 1: make it clear in your app description why you need the permission (ie part of core functionality)
- Let's suppose your app is not malicious. Suppose it wants to send an SMS to alert someone when something is stolen.
- In [the help centre article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303) it says under "Alternatives to common use cases" under "Initiate a text message" it says "With the SMS Intent, your apps can initiate an SMS or MMS text message." and gives [a link to the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage). So you should probably use this.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: i was use SMS permission for send sms when thief phone and thief person change the sim then in background send SMS to register mobile number .

In current working app i was hide the coding of particulate sens sms.